# Visual Studio Code: path of files in CMake Tools tab is incorrect

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake

I hope this is not a duplicate, as I have been searching the web for a while looking for solutions to my issue.

So, I am working in this C++ project from the lab I work at which works just fine in CLion and Visual Studio. However, I'm trying to run it in my local machine with Visual Studio Code and have installed the extensions C/C++ and CMake Tools by Microsoft, and CodeLLDB by Vadim Chugunov.

When I open the folder which contains the CMakeLists.txt file and locate it with the CMake extension, the project is detected and mounted just fine in the CMake tab. The project structure is there, and I can even build it. However, I am not able to access the files through the CMake tab (to edit them and insert breakpoints), as I get this error:

> Unable to open 'main.cpp': Unable to read file
>   '/home/leonardo/Git/MPMc/MPMc/cmake/Git/MPMc/MPMc/MPM/main/main.cpp'
>   (Error: Unable to resolve non-existing file
>   '/home/leonardo/Git/MPMc/MPMc/cmake/Git/MPMc/MPMc/MPM/main/main.cpp').

I see it is reasonable that the program cannot read the file, as its address is looped within itself. So what I really wanted was to know how to avoid this behavior so VS Code could see the real address of the files and allow me to access them.

BTW, I am running a Manjaro 18 system and didn't have the same problem with the lab machine, which runs Debian 10.

Could you guys give me any tip as to what could be the solution to this issue? Is this a VS Code issue or a system issue?

Thanks!